# AngularJS - Angularchart - Error has no method 'width'

Tags: javascript, angularjs

when I try to use Angular-chart, I have got this error :

```
TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'width'
at e (http://localhost:8080/lib/angular/angular-charts.min.js:1:10690)
at http://localhost:8080/lib/angular/angular.js:6680:44
at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:8080/lib/angular/angular.js:6271:13)
at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:8080/lib/angular/angular.js:5678:15)
at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:8080/lib/angular/angular.js:6265:24)
at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:8080/lib/angular/angular.js:5682:15)
at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:8080/lib/angular/angular.js:5685:13)
at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:8080/lib/angular/angular.js:5685:13)
at publicLinkFn (http://localhost:8080/lib/angular/angular.js:5587:30)
at http://localhost:8080/lib/angular/angular.js:1306:27 <div ac-chart="chartType" ac-data="data"     ac-config="config" id="chart" class="chart ng-isolate-scope">
```

Do you know how to fix this ? I haven't found anything helpful on internet.

Here is my code :

HTML

```
 <!doctype html>

<html lang="en" ng-app="MYaPP">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>myApp</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
  <script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/angular/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/angular/angular-charts.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="top" align="center"> Risk Proxy Manager </div>

<br></br>



<div class="plotGraph" ng-controller='plotGraph'>
    <div ac-chart="chartType" ac-data="data" ac-config="config" id='chart' class='chart'></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

App:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['angularCharts']);

function plotGraph($scope){
console.log("And here is the graph part");

//Graph
$scope.data = {
    series: ['Sales', 'Income', 'Expense', 'Laptops', 'Keyboards'],
    data : [{
        x : "Sales",
        y: [100,500, 0],
        tooltip:"this is tooltip"
    },
    {
        x : "Not Sales",
        y: [300, 100, 100]
    },
    {
        x : "Tax",
        y: [351]
    },
    {
        x : "Not Tax",
        y: [54, 0, 879]
    }]     
}

$scope.chartType = 'bar';

$scope.config = {
    labels: false,
    title : "Not Products",
    legend : {
        display:true,
        position:'left'
    }
}

$scope.config1 = {
    labels: false,
    title : "Products",
    legend : {
        display:true,
        position:'right'
    }
}
}
```

And the css :

```
.graph{
    float:left;
width: 50%;
height:400px;
}
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Thank you

Comment: paste a plunkr example

Comment: Can you show your code please?

Comment: Yes I have put it,sorry

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hello I had the same issue.  Make sure you look at the installation instructions on here http://chinmaymk.github.io/angular-charts/ .

I solved it first by making sure my dependencies were loading in the correct order. This extension relies on d3 and Jquery.

This is the order it recommends

```
<script type='text/javascript' href='./bower_components/jquery/jquery.min.js'></script> 
<script type='text/javascript' href='./bower_components/angular/angular.min.js'></script> 
<script type='text/javascript' href='./bower_components/d3/d3.min.js'></script> 
<script type='text/javascript' href='./bower_components/angular-charts/dist/angular-charts.min.js'></script>
```

After I fixed this the next error I got was...

`Error: Please set height and width for the chart element`

It turns out in order for the height and width of the graph to be set you have to set the height and width of the chart with CSS.  I found this answer through this issue on the angular-charts repo. https://github.com/chinmaymk/angular-charts/issues/12

I added this code to my css...

```
#chart {
  height: 400px;
  width: 800px;
}
```

And viola it worked! Hopes this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved, very important set

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

and

```
<script data-require="angular.js@1.2.2" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.2/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.2"></script>
```

on the top!!!